how to install libgeographiclib-dev
rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO --skip-keys libgeographiclib-dev
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y libgeographiclib-dev]
[sudo] password for ck:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libgeographiclib-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
libgeographic-dev:i386 libgeographic-dev
E: Package 'libgeographiclib-dev' has no installation candidate
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y libgeographiclib-dev] failed
I have installed libgeographic-dev and it still gives me an error.
rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO
rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO --skip-keys libgeographiclib-dev #no use

Run update command to update package repositories and get latest package information.
sudo apt-get update -y

Run the install command with -y flag to quickly install the packages and dependencies.
sudo apt-get install -y libgeographiclib-dev

